# How to actually implement a global phase gate?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, quantum-information, quantum-computer

I've been trying to model some single qubit gates via Rabi oscillations for a project. In this we have some Hamiltonian (in this case it's due to an oscillating electromagnetic field) that when applied for a specific time and with the right parameters produces the desired unitary evolution of the initial state.

However at the end I have an additional global phase factor of $-i$. This is expected and some stuff I've read even vaguely mentions how we might go about removing this but never in enough detail to be of help. I know that the global phase is not particularly important because it's entirely unobservable, but it is my understanding that it can matter in more complicated quantum circuits or in some situations. In any case, I need it to be removed and can't just ignore it because that goes against the point of what I am doing.

How do we actually do this? I haven't been able to find any resource say much more than "it's trivial and we just ignore it" when I look. The global phase gate is

$\begin{bmatrix}
e^{i \phi} & 0 \\
0 & e^{i \phi} 
\end{bmatrix}$

but how do we actually transform the qubit according to this? What is the Hamiltonian? I have not been able to find one that works, is there some other procedure? If you know the answer in the context of Rabi oscillations this would be extra helpful but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Quantum states are only defined *up to a global phase*. Thus, it is not meaningful to implement a "global phase gate", in fact, quantum gates are, for the same reason, also only defined up to a global phase.

Thus, to change the global phase, you simply have to do nothing: The state with a different global phase is simply the state you already have.

From a more "practical" point of view, one way to get a different global phase is to shift the energy in your Hamiltonian by a constant.

Comment: So to be clear, global phase truly doesn't matter in ANY context in a quantum computer? It just seems to me that if I went to the store and bought a Hadamard gate (metaphorically speaking) and inside the box was actually a Hadamard gate plus a global phase that what I have is not quite a Hadamard gate.

Comment: @rb101 There would not way for you to even test. Global phases are meaningless. If you wish, they are a flaw of the pure state formulation of quantum mechanics; if you work with density matrices, the phase drops out immediately. -- Then again, if the Hadamard gate you bought had a "control" input, which you could use to switch on and off the gate, then the phase of the gate (relative to the phase of the "switched off" identity operation) would matter.

Comment: So it DOES matter? If there is some quantum circuit where it matters, for example using CNOT or any other "controlled" gate or something else like you said, then I can't just say "we ignore it" in my project.

Comment: @rb101 No, it is simply a different device: Purchasing a controlled-Hadamard is just a different thing than purchasing a Hadamard gate, and it will be significantly more expensive. And the phase is no longer global, as there is a way to test ist. (That being said, the control must be a *quantum* input. If it isn't, then again, making claims about the global phase of the gate simply means that the person who is selling the gate is a fraud.)

Comment: Note that in the "controlled" setup, it is clear how to implement a "global" gate: Simply implement diag(1,exp(i*phi)) on the control qubit: This will implement a "global" phase on the target if and only if the control is |1>.